# pgfplots: Using $\to$ in a legend entry

Tags: math-mode, pgfplots

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \addlegendentry{$\to$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> ! Missing control sequence inserted.\inaccessible
>   \addlegendentry{$\to$}

- I wanted to use `$\to$` in a legend entry in `pgfplots` but this leads to an error.
- Other math stuff works fine, e. g. `\addlegendentry{$\alpha$}` works.
- The **solution** so far is to encapsulate it with **extra pair of curly brackets**: `\addlegendentry{{$\to$}}`.
- Is this an expected behavior? What is so special about `$\to$`?

### Edit

> There is already a `pgfplots` bug report:
>   https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/149/ Solution at the moment (March 2017) is to use `\rightarrow`.

Comment: `\to` is used (wrongly, in my opinion) for parsing arguments. If you use `\rightarrow` it works. See https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/149/

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Is `pgfplots` or `tikz` the problem then? Strange that I could not google that problem. If you **turn the comment into an answer** then I will accept (of course). But I am hitting the gym now and will be able to accept in 1-2 hours.

Comment: @egreg Never mind -- I just saw your duplicate tag. Now it's clear. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll add another comment to the issue report.